# SharePoint 'forms' hidden folder

Tags: list-form, aspx

I'm bulk uploading shared documents from a MOSS 2007 - to SharePoint 2013 - the SharePoint library has a hidden folder called 'forms' - all the templates and system forms (aspx files) are stored here for instance, allitems.aspx, editform.aspx and dispform.aspx etc. - I would like to know if I really need to keep these files from the MOSS 2007 or could I just delete them - it seems these are old and outdated info path templates no longer in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the new, display, and edit forms in your library, and are just migrating documents, then no, do not migrate the 2007 forms.